# Do I need to update references in my GUI Extension Config for 2013 SP1?

Tags: gui-extensions

I am updating my [CopyURI GUI Extension](https://github.com/rcurlette/CopyUri) for Tridion 2013 sp1.  I use Yoav's suggestions in his [8 steps article](http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/setting-up-a-tridion-gui-2011-extension-in-8-steps/) to add the XSD files to Visual Studio and validate against them.  The SDL Live Content (Login required) contains a [nice working example.](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-ACE0B7E2-31DC-40CC-BEC5-B3D6FD76EDE5&addHistory=true&query=gui%2520extension%2520config&scope=&tid=c0f171d3-2b87-4cf3-bca5-841b833f668e&filename=GUID-ACE0B7E2-31DC-40CC-BEC5-B3D6FD76EDE5.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-ACE0B7E2-31DC-40CC-BEC5-B3D6FD76EDE5&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=gui%2520extension%2520config&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1399362058243&currentQuery=gui%2520extension%2520config&currentScope=)  My question is this - do I need to update my refs to Tridion 2013 in the config?  Would it be better?  Or, can I keep them as 2011 and it is OK?  The changes I discovered are:

```
 <ext:editorextensions>
         <ext:itemicons />
```

And also

```
<settings>
    <dependencies />
    <defaultpage>/Views/Default.aspx</defaultpage>
    <editurls />
    <!--
    <navigatorurl>/Views/Default.aspx</navigatorurl>
    -->
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What references? In general, though, I can say that there is no backwards compatibility for the configuration XML so it needs to always conform to the schema of the Tridion version you have installed.

Comment: The namespace refs in the Tridion example are from 2009 - I guess that is correct?  And, I'm not sure the 2011Extensions.Commands.CopyUri in my config is correct or should be changed

Comment: The namespace hasn't changed, so 2009 is correct. As for your configuration I cannot say without seeing it - but you can always check the CME editor configuration for "inspiration" if you are in doubt :) Very little has changed over the years so I'm not sure you even need to change anything. Do you get errors?

Comment: No errors, but always curious is I'm doing it the right.  :)

Comment: Well I can't really tell. But unless it's listed in the upgrade documentation, you shouldn't have to change anything at all.

Comment: Rob - did you get this resolved?

Comment: No cosmetic or serious changes are needed when upgrading to Tridion 2013 sp1.  The APIs and config files in Tridion continue to be very backwards-compatible friendly :)

Comment: "The namespace refs in the Tridion example are from 2009" Can you add a fragment of your configuration showing that? The question will be a lot easier to understand with a relevant config sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No cosmetic or serious changes are needed when upgrading to Tridion 2013 sp1. The APIs and config files in Tridion continue to be very backwards-compatible friendly :)